# Generate and Download SQLite DB

Tags: php, sqlite

I am doing a project where a certain user can actually get/download a configuration file which is in `sqlite(.db)`form.

Is there any possibility where a PHP can compile the data into sqlite and directly serve it to the user?

What I knew is the PHP can actually create an sqlite db in the server. And I find it inefficient for my instance.

Comment: You can create a db, save data, transmit to the user and remove db-file after that.

Comment: that's what I have in mind, but that is definitely inefficient.

Comment: You know the whole task looks weird. :)

Comment: what I'm doing is an application management thingy where user can actually download configurations which is in .db form, like what I have stated in the post.

Comment: Well, if you want to do in a better way you should try to find out how sqlite keeps data in the db file. So you can create a file and write to it directly using a specific alg.